# Outlining IF-ELSE code block in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Wondering if there is anyway way to expand/collapse the IF-ELSE code block in VS2010? Sometimes the code inside IF-ELSE is too long and I would like to hide it.

Anyway one know? Thanks a lot!

EDIT: Please be informed that I'm using #region & #endregion inside the IF-ELSE statement. Try looking for more convenient style like JScript extension does.

Comment: It's not really a great answer, but: the jscript extension does it by providing it's own outliner that knows how to denote those regions.  You can write a pretty simple one that uses either matched { } characters or indentation level to provide your own outlining.  If you are interested in that, let me know, and I can give you some pointers to get started.

Comment: Thanks Noah. Yes, I'm interested. Please advice. :)

Answer (score 5):

Go to the Options dialog box and select Text Editor, expand C/C++, and then click Formatting. Activate "Automatic outlining of statement blocks."

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x6hx0kx.aspx

I'm using the full version of Visual Studio 2010, don't know if this is available in the express version.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using Ultimate version and still not working. I'm using C# and according to the MSDN you post, it should work. Weird.

Comment: Oh, sorry, wrong language then. Doesn't seem to be available for C# in my version (Professional) either. Weird indeed.

Answer (score 3):

Try surrounding the if-else with a region:

```
#region regionName
if()
{
   #region regionName
   #endregion
}
else
{
}
#endregion
```

You can also select the block you want to hide and press Ctrl+M,Ctrl+H

or

Select the block -> right click it -> Outlining -> Hide Selection

So

You will have a '+' on the left to hide and show it when you want.

Comment: Thanks guys. That's the way I'm using so far. Trying to find the way more easier and faster. I mean it would be nice if I can expand/collapse the code block natively in the IDE.

Comment: Select the block -> right click it -> Outlining -> Hide Selection ; //great tip!

Answer (score 3):

you can add regions, regions are collapsable

```
#region Name
if()
{
    ///code
}
endregion
```

Comment: Thanks but that's what I'm using. Looking for more :(

Answer (score 0):

Go to Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Formatting -> Indentation. Tick "Indent open and close brackets".